# How to print kernel time from command line?

Tags: dmesg, uptime

How can I convert the `uptime` output to seconds since epoch to compare with `dmesg` output? Does uptime have the same resolution as the kernel message time?  Is there a way to more directly get the kernel time than from `uptime`?

```
➜  ~ echo "hi" > /dev/kmsg
➜  ~ dmesg | tail
[  859.214564] hi
➜  ~ uptime
10:08  up 2 days, 43 secs, 2 users, load averages: 1.69 1.64 1.54
```

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking. `dmesg` output isn't seconds since the epoch.  What problem are you trying to solve?  Are you talking purely about 'time since boot' rather than epoch or kernel time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on your flavor of Unix, the `/proc` filesystem may have an uptime file somewhere with the information you want.

```
Linux> cat /proc/uptime
5899847.37 23165596.55
```

And the output of the `uptime` command for the same time:

```
Linux> uptime
16:46:27 up 68 days, 6:51,  3 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.02, 0.05
```

So 5899847.37/86400 = 68.28527 --> 68 days, 6 hours, 51 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

kernel time is stored as seconds since Jan 1, 1970.  Are you looking to see that as a value?  Or are you looking to see what actual date/time the kernel thinks it is?

For the latter, you can just use `date -u`.

If you want the current seconds since 1st Jan 1970 (epoch), and have `perl` installed you can run `perl -e 'print time()."\n";'`

You can also use the `date` command, using `date +"%s"` which returns the same information.

If you want to know how long the system has been up, the `uptime` is the best tool.

Comment: how can i convert the uptime output to seconds since epoch to compare with dmesg output?  does uptime have the same resolution as the kernel message time?

Comment: Okay that's a *completely* different question, you might want to update your question to make that clear.